# Why AWS lambda execution gave me an error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

```
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

For this Lambda I have already attached a policy to the lambda role

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "s3:PutObject",
          "s3:PutObjectTagging"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::(the bucket I want to put object to)*"
    },
```

Why it's still complaining? Is it because I need to add a write permission to this s3 bucket? Thanks.

Comment: What is this `${aws_s3_bucket.xxxxxxxxxx}`? Where is this `$` comming from?

Comment: I've updated my question, it's the arn for the s3 bucket that I want lambda to put object to, am I missing something? Do I need to grant lambda access from s3 side?

Comment: Is the bucket in the same account? Are there any existing policies on the bucket? If its same account, you don't need to do anything on s3 side, unless you already have some policies that block the access.

Comment: What about KMS? Is the bucket encrypted? If it is, then lambda also needs kms permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing the `s3:PutObjectAcl` Permission to do that.

[Here are some more ways to solve this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-403-upload-bucket/)

I think this could solve your problem:

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "s3:PutObject",
          "s3:PutObjectTagging",
          "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::(the bucket I want to put object to)/*"
    },
```

Comment: You mean on the Lambda policy side? Do I still need to add something on the s3 side?

Comment: add s3:PutObjectAcl in your policy that you posted above i will update my answer

Comment: I just had a try but I'm still getting the same error, I wonder is it because I should also tell the bucket to allow lambda to putobject?

Comment: It should work from both ways can you try to set the resource like this `"Resource":  "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName/*"

Comment: Yeah it works, my bad, I'm pointing it to the wrong bucket.... Thanks :)